What does "OTB folder not set" mean?
I installed QGIS version 3.34 Prizren today. There were no problems with the install.
As soon as I opened it there is a message in the message log under Processing Tab that reads:

2024-05-30T20:35:11     CRITICAL    Problem with OTB installation: OTB folder is not set.

I have only been using QGIS for a little less than 2 years and still learning all the ins and outs; what does this error code mean and how do to resolve the issue?

All will be explained if you read the the setup instructions linked to on the plugin details tab https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/QGISInterface.html

It says "Instructions only valid since QGIS 3.36"
I am running 3.34
And I still don't know what OTB actually is or does and why I need it installed.

That only refers to installing the plugin. See the configuration section below. OTB is specialised remote sensing software. if you don't use OTB you can just disable the plugin.
